# Xamarin Forms android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have an app that's been running for years, and suddenly it has started crashing (With new builds).
My findings is that after you have visited a page with a webview the app will crash. Not on the page with the webview but after you left that page.
I get this exception
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1 in se.xx.yy:layout/shellcontent: Binary XML file line #1 in se.xx.yy

Can also see this in the stack trace:
at Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 37: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030007 a=13}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f10020bse.xx.yy:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar, id=0x7f10006cse.xx.yy:style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar, id=0x7f10006bse.xx.yy:style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark, id=0x7f10010ase.xx.yy:style/Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark

Any advice?

/Lars

Comment: Can you provide some code or edit your question to make it more clear? You can put these errors in the code format.

Comment: The problem is that the app just crashes hard, it doesn't hit my Exception breakpoint.
For example, I open a modal page with a webview. Close the modal view, then if a do any navigation in the app it will crash. It hits the exception in ExceptionServicesCommon.cs

Comment: First, you can check the nuget package you used and upgrade the package. Second, you can check the  AppShell and the navigation page.

Comment: If you mean Forms nuget, i'ts the latest version. What specifically should I check in the AppShell?